# How to compile dpdk without avx for kvm centos

Tags: kvm, avx, dpdk

I need to run my application on kvm. 
The image(centos 6.3) that run on kvm does not contain avx. 
But the computer i compile dpdk on it, have kvm.

I think i should compile dpdk without avx,
Is this possible, and how can i do it?

I know that there is or not avx by running the following command:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep avx --color
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compile DPDK without AVX by commenting/removing the following lines in `mk/rte.cpuflags.mk`

```
ifneq ($(filter $(AUTO_CPUFLAGS),__AVX__),)
CPUFLAGS += AVX
endif
```